# How to create OpenCV images that are contiguous in memory?

Tags: opencv, memory-management

I am an **OpenCV** newbie. I create a OpenCV image using `cvCreateImage` and apply some operations on it. Now, I want to create a series of OpenCV images whose underlying memory is **contiguous**. This can be helpful to process that memory later as a series of image frames using parallel or CUDA techniques.

How can I create a certain number of OpenCV images that are contiguous in memory?

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate the data yourself:

```cpp
const int W = 640;
const int H = 480;
const int C = 1;  // number of channels (1 for CV_8U)
const int N = 10; // number of images
unsigned char buffer[W*H*C*N];

cv::Mat im0(H, W, CV_8U, buffer);
cv::Mat im1(H, W, CV_8U, buffer + W*H*C);
cv::Mat im2(H, W, CV_8U, buffer + W*H*C*2);
```

I have used the C++ API because I'm more used to it, but there must exist a similar behaviour in the C api with the `cvCreateImage` function.

Comment: I would not advise allocating the image buffers on the stack. It would be a very easy way to overflow the stack and crash the program. Better to allocate it on the heap with `new` or `malloc`.

Comment: If you overflow the buffer, isn't the program going to crash regardless of where you allocated the buffer? Better to never use new or malloc, unless you are writing a library, especially if you are a newbie. IMO, a std::vector (e.g.) is often preferable to direct allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cv::Mat to manage the storage, then you don't to have remember to delete the storage.
Assuming 3 channel images:

```
const int W = 640; const int H = 480; const int C = 1;
const int N = 10; // number of images
cv::Mat buffer (N, W * H, CV_8UC3);

cv::Mat im0(H, W, CV_8UC3, buffer.ptr<uchar>(0));
cv::Mat im1(H, W, CV_8UC3, buffer.ptr<uchar>(1));
cv::Mat im2(H, W, CV_8UC3, buffer.ptr<uchar>(2));
```